# Measure the size of an image and use the width/height values within data-size

Tags: javascript

I need to find the width and the height of the images (dynamically) and then load them into the `data-size` element.

It will end up looking like `data-size="768x472"`

I used this code:

```
<script>

function realImgDimension(img) {
    var i = new Image();
    i.src = img.src;
    return {
        naturalWidth: i.width, 
        naturalHeight: i.height
    };
}

var myImage = document.getElementsByClassName('myImage');
    myImage.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var realSize = realImgDimension(this);
  console.log('My width is: ', realSize.naturalWidth);
  console.log('My height is: ', realSize.naturalHeight);
});
</script>
```

The error I'm getting in my console is `blog:741 Uncaught TypeError: myImage.addEventListener is not a function`

From Googling around I think it's because you can't add an `addeventlistener` in this way in Javascript.

Comment: What JS you have running (give a snippet)?  What do you mean by "prints verbose"?

Comment: show your initial efforts/code

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Would this cause the downvotes?

Comment: People might downvote because you have multiple questions (how to add a data-size attribute, how to add event listeners to images, how to debug my code) and you fail to isolate your issue to a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve by talking about grids, blog entries and so on... which makes the question very long.

Comment: Thanks @le_m I have amended my question to reduce the size of it.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating information of the image element (naturalWidth, naturalHeight) by adding both into a data-size attribute is probably not what you *really* need (or do you need IE8 support?) - since you could always directly query the image.naturalWidth and image.naturalHeight instead...

Still, you can do so as follows:

- How to add the data-size attribute to elements? Use
  `element.dataset.size = ...;`
- How to attach event listeners to elements? Use `element.addEventListener(...);`

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
  images[i].addEventListener("load", (event) => {
    var image = event.target;
    image.dataset.size = image.naturalWidth + "x" + image.naturalHeight;
    console.log(image.dataset.size);
  });
}
```

```html
<image class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGMoC.png">
<image class="image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar">
```

Your code probably fails because `document.getElementsByClassName('myImage')` returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which doesn't have an `addEventListener()` method - only the individual elements have.

If you want to attach above event listener to all images with class 'myImage', you need to iterate over the result of `var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImage');` and add above event listener to all individual images instead of just the first one (`image[0]`).

Comment: Thanks this is a great explanation.  I was under the impression that as I was using a foreach loop, using an ID on the image was a bad idea, as ID's are supposed to be unique i.e. only on one element.  I switched it to a class for that reason.  Does that make sense or am I wrong?

And my apologies, I had removed [0] but not updated my answer

Comment: Querying images according to class is surely better, the id was just for this example. I modified my answer to show you how to attach that event listener to the result of getElementsByClassName() - which is an `HTMLCollection`-object: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Gracias amigo, and thanks for the awesome link.  I'll get there in the end :)

Comment: I still get the same error using your code.  `Uncaught TypeError: image.addEventListener is not a function`.  How can this be?  I can see your working example.

Comment: Insert `console.log(image);` before that call and have a look at the output - `getElementsByClassName();` returns `undefined` if it doesn't find any elements.

Comment: Interesting, quite a lot of stuff comes up.  Pretty neat.  `[img.g-popupgrid-item-img-wrap-img.image, img.g-popupgrid-item-img-wrap-img.image]` maybe it's because it has another class as well as the `.image` class?

Comment: Correct. All elements having the image class are returned (they can have additional other classes). I recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for such questions about built-in JS functions, they are pretty well explained.

Comment: Ok this issue was to do with context.  I had put the code within a PHP file that was being called by another.  I moved it to the parent and hey presto it worked.  Thanks for your help.  On to the next problem.